# Unblocking the web server?

Tags: python, django

I am using the below given function in python flask to download file stored in telegram cloud.Everything is working fine, the problem arises when size of file is large, it blocks whole web server until the download is complete. So please tell me how I can make it run parallel without blocking the server.

```
def ping_me(chat_id,user,im_name):
   os.system('tgcloud -m download -n admin_helper -u "assignment_collector_bot" -p 
   "portal/static/documents/users/"'+str(user.telegram_id)+'"/temp/" -c "'+im_name+'"')
   return Response('ok',status=200)
```

Comment: You seem to have a single threaded deployment and additionally you might have a shell code injection vulnerability.

Comment: Need to do it as a background task using celery, and send an email to the user with the link to the download. Also you can possibly forward the telegram download link to the client, to not do all this. Telegram must have a function for generating download links to assets.